# Group by a pandas dataframe by 15 min time intervals but for the whole day

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have the follwing dataframe i'd like to group by 15 minutes bin and sum the column Q, but i would like to have these bins for the whole day.

```
 time                   Q
 2019-12-07 09:13:00   10 
 2019-12-07 09:33:00    1 
 2019-12-07 09:41:00    1 
 2019-12-07 10:03:00    6 
 2019-12-07 10:15:00    5 
 2019-12-07 10:37:00    3 
 2019-12-07 10:48:00   15 
 2019-12-07 11:05:00    3 
 2019-12-07 11:16:00    8 
 2019-12-07 11:34:00    5 
 2019-12-07 11:48:00   10 
 2019-12-07 12:01:00    6 
 2019-12-07 12:18:00    7
```

so I would like to have for examples the beans like this:

```
time                  SUM(Q)
 2019-12-07 00:00:00               
 2019-12-07 00:15:00
 2019-12-07 00:30:00
 2019-12-07 00:45:00
 2019-12-07 01:00:00
               .
               .
               .
2019-12-07 23:00:00
2019-12-07 23:15:00
2019-12-07 23:30:00
2019-12-07 23:45:00
```

I have tried

```
 df.groupby(df.time.dt.floor('15T'))["Q"].sum()
```

and

```
 df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key="time", freq="15Min"))['Q'].sum()
```

but they both  group by only for available times in the column not from the start of the day (00:00:00 or 00:15:00) to the end of day ( 23:45:00)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `00:00:00` to minimal `time` and `23:45:00` to maximal, so in ouput are all expected values:

```
s = df['time'].agg(['min','max']).dt.normalize().copy()
s['max'] = s['max'] + pd.DateOffset(hours=23, minutes=45)

df = df.append(s.to_frame().assign(Q = 0), ignore_index=True)   
print (df)
                  time   Q
0  2019-12-07 09:13:00  10
1  2019-12-07 09:33:00   1
2  2019-12-07 09:41:00   1
3  2019-12-07 10:03:00   6
4  2019-12-07 10:15:00   5
5  2019-12-07 10:37:00   3
6  2019-12-07 10:48:00  15
7  2019-12-07 11:05:00   3
8  2019-12-07 11:16:00   8
9  2019-12-07 11:34:00   5
10 2019-12-07 11:48:00  10
11 2019-12-07 12:01:00   6
12 2019-12-07 12:18:00   7
13 2019-12-07 00:00:00   0
14 2019-12-07 23:45:00   0
```

And then use your solution, e.g.:

```
df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key="time", freq="15Min"))['Q'].sum()
```

If need processing each dates separately - first use your solution and then add misisng `Datetimes` by [`Series.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reindex.html):

```
print (df)
                  time   Q
0  2019-12-07 09:13:00  10
1  2019-12-07 09:33:00   1
2  2019-12-07 09:41:00   1
3  2019-12-07 10:03:00   6
4  2019-12-07 10:15:00   5
5  2019-12-07 10:37:00   3
6  2019-12-07 10:48:00  15
7  2019-12-07 11:05:00   3
8  2019-12-09 11:16:00   8
9  2019-12-09 11:34:00   5
10 2019-12-09 11:48:00  10
11 2019-12-09 12:01:00   6
12 2019-12-09 12:18:00   7


dates = [y for x in df.time.dt.normalize().drop_duplicates() 
           for y in pd.date_range(x, x + pd.DateOffset(hours=23, minutes=45), freq='15T')]
print (dates[:2])
[Timestamp('2019-12-07 00:00:00', freq='15T'), Timestamp('2019-12-07 00:15:00', freq='15T')]
```

---

```
df = df.groupby(df.time.dt.floor('15T'))["Q"].sum().reindex(dates, fill_value=0)
print (df)
time
2019-12-07 00:00:00    0
2019-12-07 00:15:00    0
2019-12-07 00:30:00    0
2019-12-07 00:45:00    0
2019-12-07 01:00:00    0
                      ..
2019-12-09 22:45:00    0
2019-12-09 23:00:00    0
2019-12-09 23:15:00    0
2019-12-09 23:30:00    0
2019-12-09 23:45:00    0
Name: Q, Length: 192, dtype: int64
```

Comment: thanks, actually in my use case i also have several dates stacked together so i need to have all the  bins for each date, your second proposed solution only has 00:00 and 23:45 in addition to original bins which were already available. So i think there should be something missing from the solution for processing each date separately

Comment: in the other word, all the bins for each day in your example 07.12 and 09.12

Comment: the first solution which is only for one date works perfectly.

Comment: @chessosapiens can you try for second solution ` df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key="time", freq="15Min"))['Q'].sum()`?

Comment: I already did, it is not returning desired result, i think the problem is with df.append(df1.stack().to_frame('time').assign(SALES_QUANTITY = 0), ignore_index=True)    because it only appends 4 new rows ( 2 for 00:00 and 2 for 23:45)

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, it works but it also add  ( 08.12 ) the date between 07.12 and 09.12

Comment: can i please make an update to the question to make it more similar to actual world scenario?

Comment: Great!, Thanks a lot

Comment: Is there any way to do this 15 minutes intervals using sliding windows? the reindexing ( especially when we have other level of aggregations) seems to be heavy computing.

Answer (score 0):

Given your end result so far with "the missing timestamps" (e.g. using `df.resample('15T').sum()`), you may add those missing timestamps as follows:

```py
idx = pd.date_range('2019-12-07','2019-12-08',closed='left',freq='15T')  # generates an index of timestamps every 15 minutes
df2 = df.reindex(idx, fill_value=0)
```

See [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) for more details on how it fills values in locations having no value in the previous index.